# MATLAB collecting time data

Tags: arrays, matlab, time, range

I have the following data, 'd'

```
0.0012
0.0043
0.0034
0.0108
0.0042
0.0052
0.0516
0.0034
0.0023
.... and so on
```

I know this time data ranges from `0-0.1`.
What is the best way to group this un-ordered data into time ranges.
I would want to collect the values in the range `0<=d<0.002`, `0.002<=d<0.004` and so on in the `0.002` blocks until I reach `0.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
step = .002;
limit = .1;
result = accumarray(1+floor(d(:)/step), d(:), [1+floor(limit/step), 1], @(x) {x});
```

In your example, this gives

```
>> result{1}
ans =
    0.0012
>> result{2}
ans =
    0.0034
    0.0034
    0.0023
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
range = 0:0.002:0.1;
results = cell(numel(range)-1,1);
for ii = 1:numel(range)-1
    tmp = d>range(ii) & d<range(ii+1);
    results{ii} = d(tmp);
end
```

I initialised a `range` array, containing your range specifiers. `tmp` then contains logical indices on the location within your range, which get extracted and stored in the next line. Note that I used cells, since it is not guaranteed that each range has the same amount of points in it.

Comment: You need to change `&&` into `&`

Comment: @LuisMendo why? Usually when I use `&` MATLAB complains it wants `&&`

Comment: `&&` is short-circuit `&`, and can be used _only for scalars_. `&` can be used for arrays or scalars